# How to configure namespace adjustments by ReSharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm having a problem with ReSharper refactoring I just can't find a solution to.

Whenever I'm trying to adjust a name space through refactoring, when it says "Move to 'correct.namespace' namespace", ReSharper forcefully removes unused "using" statements from all the files it fixes the namespace in and it also opens all the files.

My question is, how to prevent ReSharper from opening all the files it modifies and also how to stop it from removing unused usings?

I don't want it to open 20+ files, neither do I want it to remove the standard

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them to the `Namespace Imports` part of the Resharper Options to preserve the namespaces.

I'm not sure if its possible to prevent it from opening all of the files since it depends on so much of the VS infrastructure. Plus it would not be possible to undo without opening the files.

Comment: Your answer partially solves the issue. Adding the namespaces to the "Namespace Imports" section indeed prevents them from getting removed, but other namespaces become unused still get deleted (as expected, since they're not part of the list) and those that are part of the list show as used namespaces, even though they aren't. As for ReSharper forcing me to wait on VS to open dozens of files, something's not right. Other ReSharper commands explicitly let you switch this option, while adjusting namespaces just forces you to open them. Voting up, but waiting on potential input from other users.